# Extract absolute file path from a QRessource loaded file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, absolute-path

I have a file in /home/me/xmls/foo/bar.xml
and  a correct qrc file containing this path

The folowing code :

```
QFileInfo f (":/foo/bar.xml");
cout<<f.absoluteFilePath().toAscii().data()<<endl;
```

outputs:

> :/foo/bar.xml

when i was expecting:

> /home/me/xmls/foo/bar.xml

Is there any way to recover the absolute path in the system of a QRessource loaded file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QResource encodes its contents into a file that gets compiled into the final binary. So, no I would expect it is not possible to get the original path at run time. As the [Qt docs state](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html): -

> The Qt resource system is a platform-independent mechanism for storing binary files **in the application's executable**

Also, it doesn't make sense to want the original path, as other users are unlikely to have the file at that location.

Comment: you are right. I was misunderstanding the QResource and it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
QFileInfo f (":/foo/bar.xml");
```

means that you are going to load a file from the resource file. Basically, this is a library (static or shared), which contains resources (images, translations, etc).

That is a standard syntax to access a file in the resources, as explained [in their documentation for the resources](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application).